# Почему не работает код. flask socketio

Tags: python, flask, socketio-client

Серверная часть:

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from flask import *
import random

clients = {'user1' : {'messages' : '213'}}

server = Flask(__name__)
server.config['SECRET_KEY'] = str(random.randint(10**32, 10**64))
server_io = SocketIO(server, async_mode='gevent')

@server.route('/')
def index():
    response = make_response(render_template('test.html'))
    response.set_cookie('auth', 'user1')

    return response

@server.route('/get_messages')
def get_messages():
    emit('nm', 'test message', room=clients[request.cookies.get('auth')]['roomId'], namespace='/')

    print(clients)

    return '0'

@server_io.on('connect', namespace='/')
def connected():
    clients['user1']['roomId'] = request.sid
    print('connected!')


server.run(debug=True, port=80)
```

Клиентская часть:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:80');

        socket.on('nm', function(data) {
            console.log('nm');
            console.log(data);
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Суть в том, что при обновлении страницы '/get_messages', в консоле страницы '/' должен появиться текст 'test message', причём, у каждого клиента есть свой уникальный id (request.sid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строчку

```
server_io = SocketIO(server, async_mode='gevent')
```

Меняем на

```
server_io = SocketIO(server)
```

`@server_io.on('connect', namespace='/')` на `@server_io.on('connect')`,

А последнюю строку на `server_io.run(server, debug=True, port=80)`